# jQuery Mobile data-transition slide overlap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have several data-role="page"(s) and I use data-transition="slide" to transition to the next page.  My issue is on mobile (iOS or Android), the next page (page5) slides and overlaps the current page just for a second.  Any idea on a fix?

```
<div data-role="page" id="page4">
   <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="staticS">
      <h1>Page 4</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">    
      content here
   </div>
  <div class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="staticS">
    <a href="#page5" data-transition="slide"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related Ticket : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5764
I guess it will be fixed in JQM 1.4, time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

.ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

(duplicate of [overlap in slide transition Jquery Mobile 1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259582/overlap-in-slide-transition-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/20630157#20630157))

Courtesy of dantabel in this thread : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5764
Here's the answer !
Exchange this part of the jquery 1.3.2 source code

```
// line 3674 - jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js
startOut = function() {
    // if it's not sequential, call the doneOut transition to start the TO page animating in simultaneously
    if ( !sequential ) {
        doneOut();
    }
    else {
        $from.animationComplete( doneOut );
    }

    // Set the from page's height and start it transitioning out
    // Note: setting an explicit height helps eliminate tiling in the transitions
    $from
        .height( screenHeight + $.mobile.window.scrollTop() )
        .addClass( name + " out" + reverseClass );
},
```

With this one :

```
startOut = function() {
    if ( !sequential && reverse) {
        doneOut();
    } else if(sequential) {
        $from.animationComplete( doneOut );
    }

    $from
        .height( screenHeight + $.mobile.window.scrollTop() )
        .addClass( name + " out" + reverseClass );

    if ( !sequential && !reverse) {
        doneOut();
    }
},
```

And then it works like a charm ! (at least on iOS 7)

I guess this bug will be fixed in 1.4, we'll see :-)